# Netbeans Dynamic Type Hinting/Casting

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans

In NetBeans we can do type casting as below -

```
/**
 *
 * @var My_Db_Table_Abstract
 */
protected $_db;
```

But in my case the variable `$_db` may be instance of different classes, because it's value is assigned dynamically like below.

```
public function __construct($db) {
    $this->_db = $db;
}
```

Is it possible to make the type (here `My_Db_Table_Abstract`) dynamic?

Comment: I don't think you can make comments dynamic...

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP's type-hinting feature in your constructor's parameters to guarantee that what's passed in is an object of the type you require.

```
public function __construct (My_Db_Table_Abstract $db) {
    $this->_db = $db;
}
```

This will prevent you from passing anything except My_Db_Table_Abstract or a subclass of My_Db_Table_Abstract into your constructor.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be answer for OP's question!!

Comment: The OP was concerned that the instance variable could have something other than the expected type set on it.  The above code protects the instance variable from having an inappropriate type set on it.

Comment: I just want to get hints according to the variable.

Comment: Do you mean you want your IDE to provide method/property hints based on what kind of object was passed into the constructor?  If that's what you want, then it can't be done because there's no way for the IDE to know what's going to be passed in at runtime.